# HTML Layout quirk when inserting a tag

Tags: html, css

I have a simple layout composed of boxes.

[Fiddle of the code](http://jsfiddle.net/UZZP2/3/)

I have `<div>` tags within `<div>` tags; I'm using them to 'define' blocks where I can later print out inputs.

```
<div class=display-window>
    <div id=pieces>
    </div>    
    <div id=vline></div>
    <div id=message>
        <p>Nothing special is going on</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

When I take the `<p>` element out, the display is fine. But when it's there, the box slides down, making it way off. This is true for both `#pieces` and `#message`, here. It *seems* that the box slides until the paragraph is against its top. I want the box to *stay there*.

Shouldn't child elements leave their parents undisturbed if they can?! This feels very inflexible!

**Note**: I get widely different results between codecademy.com and fiddle.net, so it's difficult for me to tell what is going on exactly. Margins and padding solve the problem, but this is, again, inflexible: I want to remove the tags during execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has to do with your inline-block style elements. By default, all inline-block elements have a vertical-align set to baseline, which in your case is the bottom [`line-height`] (probably 16px) of your vertical line (`div#vline`) in the middle of your div.

Set the v-align to top on the p element's container and it works great:

```
#message
{
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UZZP2/5/)

Comment: Thanks for that advice. Although, I heard some people having mixed feelings on 'vertical-align', since up to IE 7 browsers were not compatible with it, or something. I'm not sure what the trend is, as of now. It does seem like a handy attribute.